# Substracting strings

Tags: java, string, methods

I am programming a game. Most of my code is working fine, but I have a few problems. The gist of the game is that there is an initial combination, and then each player gives "bets" every turn. I have to subtract these bets from the combination and announce the winning player when the combination is"000". The problem I have, is with the second bet(by player two), I can't get the substraction to work.

Here is an example of what I should get:

```
initial combination:
333
player one bet:122
211(after substracting digit individually)
player two bet:
211
=000
winner:player one
```

The things is when it comes to player two I get a value of "122" instead of "000". I would just like to know if there is a problem with my code, and if I called the method(appliquerCoup),which is the method that does the substraction, correctly.

Thank you!

```
           do{  
                if(num%2==0){
                   System.out.println(MessagesTp2.COUP_DU_JOUEUR1);
                 }else{
                  System.out.println(MessagesTp2.COUP_DU_JOUEUR2);
                 }
              coup=Clavier.lireString();
              rep=coupEstValide(combinaison,coup);
              while(rep!=true){
                System.out.println(MessagesTp2.COUP_INVALIDE);
                coup=Clavier.lireString();
               }

             nouvelleValeur=appliquerCoup(combinaison,coup);
             System.out.println("=>"+nouvelleValeur);
             num++;  
            }while(!nouvelleValeur.equals("000")); 
               if(nouvelleValeur.equals("000")){
                  if(num%2==0){
                   System.out.println(MessagesTp2.GAGNANT_JOUEUR1);
                   }else{
                  System.out.println(MessagesTp2.GAGNANT_JOUEUR2);
                }
              }

           }
    public static String appliquerCoup(String combinaison,String coup) {
       String nouveauCoup = "";
        if(combinaison!=null&&coup!=null){
        for(int i = 0; i < combinaison.length(); i++) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(combinaison.substring(i, i + 1));
            int b = Integer.parseInt(coup.substring(i, i + 1));
            int c = a - b;
                if(c < 0){
                     c=0;
                    }else{
                        c=c;
                }  
                  nouveauCoup+=String.valueOf(c);
          }
     }
        return nouveauCoup;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that, when you call `appliquerCoup(combinaison,coup)`, you always subtract `coup` from `combinaison`, which is the initial value. You assign the return value of `appliquerCoup` to `nouvelleValeur`, but `combinaison` is never reassigned. Thus, the new bet will always be subtracted from the starting value.

You will probably want to change the lines

```
do {
    [...]
    nouvelleValeur=appliquerCoup(combinaison,coup);
    System.out.println("=>"+nouvelleValeur);
    num++;  
} while(!nouvelleValeur.equals("000"));
if(nouvelleValeur.equals("000")){ [...] }
```

to

```
do {
    [...]
    combinaison=appliquerCoup(combinaison,coup);
    System.out.println("=>"+combinaison);
    num++;  
} while(!combinaison.equals("000"));
if(combinaison.equals("000")){ [...] }
```

There are a couple of other, stylistic issues with your code (you can remove the check for `combinaison.equals("000")`, for example), but that would probably be the topic of another question, since none of these appear to be gamebreaking.

Comment: UGH! Thank you! I just realized my mistake! my code works now!

Comment: Great :) I would really appreciate it if you could accept my answer :)